# SVN diff ignoring deleted files

Tags: svn

I'm really new to SVN and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I start with a repository that contains:

```
HelloWorld.java
```

I create a working set on my computer, and then copy HelloWorld.java to HelloWorldDe.java. I then rename HelloWorld.java to HelloWorldEn.java and modify a single line in HelloWorldDe.java. After this I have a working set that contains:

```
HelloWorldEn.java <-- Renamed copy of HelloWorld.java
HelloWorldDe.java <-- Renamed copy of HelloWorld.java with one line change
```

When I do SVN status i get this:

```
A HelloWorldDe.java
D HelloWorld.java
A HelloWorldEn.java
```

When I do SVN diff I get this:

```
Index: HelloWorldDe.java
===================================================================
--- HelloWorldDe.java   (revision 0)
+++ HelloWorldDe.java   (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+public class HelloWorld {
+  public static void main( String [] args ) {
+    System.out.println("Hallo welt!");
+  }
+}
Index: HelloWorld.java
===================================================================
--- HelloWorld.java (revision 13)
+++ HelloWorld.java (working copy)
@@ -1,5 +0,0 @@
-public class HelloWorld {
-  public static void main( String [] args ) {
-    System.out.println("Hello World!");
-  }
-}
Index: HelloWorldEn.java
===================================================================
--- HelloWorldEn.java   (revision 0)
+++ HelloWorldEn.java   (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+public class HelloWorld {
+  public static void main( String [] args ) {
+    System.out.println("Hello World!");
+  }
+}
```

However when i try to run "patch -p0 -i German.diff" on the original working set, I end up with this:

```
HelloWorld.java <-- Empty file
HelloWorldEn.java
HelloWorldDe.java
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting an empty file instead of the file being deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because patch does not delete files. It only modifies them with the content in the patch file. So this:

```
--- HelloWorld.java (revision 13)
+++ HelloWorld.java (working copy)
@@ -1,5 +0,0 @@
-public class HelloWorld {
-  public static void main( String [] args ) {
-    System.out.println("Hello World!");
-  }
-}
```

Won't delete HelloWorld.java, it will only remove all the lines indicated with a `-`, which is all of them.

If you'd have committed the changes you made and then run `svn up` the file would have been deleted. But patch is not svn.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I think I need a break, it didn't occur to me that patch is not part of svn for some reason.


Is there a way for me to create a patch that will delete the file?

Comment: I believe it's possible but it's a little tricky, I forget the details right now. The method is described in patch's man page, you should be able to find it if you Google "patch man".

Answer (score 1):

### 1. First, a few questions

1. What version of `subversion` are you using? (see part 3)
2. How are you generating *German.diff*?  Are we to assume that *German.diff* looks exactly like the output from `svn diff` that you presented?

### 2. Patch *does* remove files

`patch` does delete files that **itself makes empty by deleting all lines**, usually by default, but as mentioned in the man page, it depends on the implementation. From `man patch`:

> **-E  or  --remove-empty-files**
>
> Remove  output  files that are empty after the patches have been applied.  Normally this option is unnecessary, since
>   patch can examine the time stamps on the header to determine whether a file should exist after patching.  However, if
>   the  input is not a context diff or if patch is conforming to POSIX, patch does not remove empty patched files unless
>   this option is given.  When patch removes a file, it also attempts to remove any empty ancestor directories.

You can either force this option or force `--posix` to get deterministic behavior.  If you do, `patch` should delete that file.

NOTE: *Empty* can be misleading.  Is it really empty, as in size = 0 bytes?  Or just a `\n` char in there, no text?  I've found that truly empty files are a nightmare with `patch`, but if it causes them to be empty it should delete them.

### 3. `svn` has a bug

Some versions of svn diff don't put the moved/renamed/deleted files in the diff at all! And it depends on how you call diff. So ***please confirm*** that the patch file you are giving to `patch` (*German.diff*), ***actually has an entry*** for that file in the patch, otherwise you might be suffering from this.

See: http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2004-03/0333.shtml. This archived email from the SVN DEV list shows the devs themselves identified this problem, sometime before 1.0.1 was released, over a decade ago.

In my experience, this issue was fixed in SVN 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this, you could use the -E option of the patch command to force it to delete empty files after they are patched.

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/patch.htm